# How do I make a column in a MySQL table unique?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `QUES` in mysql database.

The table has a column `BODY` which is not unique at present.

The table has many rows of these I am sure that currently the `BODY` is unique by nature but not defined as a property.

How can I update the column `BODY` with unique defined as property as well?

Can someone suggest the correct sql query for the same?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE QUES ADD UNIQUE (BODY).
```

Read the fine manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: not working as column "body" is longvarchar.. is there any other solution.?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some example SQL statements that may help get you started. This assumes that `body` is a character type column, and that you want to "preserve" as much of the existing value as possible, and appending a unique string to make it "more unique".

```
-- find values of `body` that are "duplicated" in the table
SELECT q.body
     , COUNT(1) as cnt_
  FROM ques q
 GROUP BY q.body
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

That query just gets us the particular values of `body` that are "duplicates", and a count of the number of rows that share that value. We need to be able to identify the rows that have these unique values, so we can run a query like this:

```
-- find all rows that have one of the "duplicated" values
SELECT s.id
     , s.body
  FROM (SELECT q.body
          FROM ques q
         WHERE q.body IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP BY q.body
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) r
  JOIN ques s ON s.body = r.body
```

Those are the rows that we would need to update. To make these unique, we can assign a new unique value to the `body` column for each of those rows. If none of the "new" values duplicates a value that already exists in the table, we'll have unique values.

Example update statement:

```
-- append unique value to end of each body value
UPDATE (SELECT q.body
          FROM ques q
         WHERE q.body IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP BY q.body
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) r
  JOIN ques s ON s.body = r.body
   SET s.body = CONCAT(s.body,'<!--',s.id,'-->');
```

Here we are "appending" a value to the end of the existing body value. We can make use of an existing column in the table that is guaranteed to be NOT NULL and unique. An AUTO_INCREMENT primary key column is a suitable candidate. (We could have the statement generate a unique integer instead.)

NOTE: There is no guarantee that the new value we are assigning to `body` is different from a value that already exists in the database. We're just identifying existing duplicates, and then applying changes so that the values are unique from each other. We'd really need to circle back, and check for duplicate values again.

Also note that there's no check done here for the maximum length of the `body` column, that is whether there is "room" at the end of each existing value to append a string of a given format. So there's room for improvement there, checking the size of the existing `body` value (using the `LENGTH()` or `CHAR_LENGTH()` function) and comparing that to the column definition.

Also, if there 2 rows with a duplicate value, we really only need to update one of the rows them, and we can leave one of them with the existing value. The example query doesn't do this right now, but it could be made to.

But this should be enough to get you started.

Of course, once you've gotten the values to be unique, you'll want to add a UNIQUE constraint on this column, to prevent duplicates from being created in the future.

---

This demonstrates how we could leave the value of body for one row unchanged. (A corresponding UPDATE statement would assign that `IF()` expression to the body column.)

```
-- show new values for body, leave the value for one row unchanged
SELECT s.id
     , s.body AS old_val
     , IF(s.id = q.min_id, s.body, CONCAT(s.body,'<!--',s.id,'-->')) AS new_val
  FROM (SELECT q.body
             , MIN(q.id) AS min_id
          FROM ques q
         WHERE q.body IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY q.body
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) r
  JOIN ques s ON s.body = r.body
```